# Поворот карты Yandex Map API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При разработке потребовалось повернуть карту, используется API версии 2.1. В документации не нашёл методов для этого, подскажите есть ли возможность повернуть карту, как она это делает на карте яндекса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update [26.12.2022]
Пример вращения карты на ПК: https://codesandbox.io/s/wvi4po?initialpath=react.html

Такое поведение карты удалось найти только в API версии 3.0 (mouseRotate, pinchRotate): https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/dg/concepts/events.html#behavior-type

При этом не совсем понятно как делать поворот мышкой, в документации об этом речи нет.
Пример, работающий только на сенсорном экране: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-galois-9q570n?file=/vanilla.html&initialpath=vanilla.html